# Google Bigquery API in Google App Script Throwing Error (Response Code 413: 'response too large') While Joining Relatively Small Size Tables

Tags: join, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am facing a 413 error (response too large)  from BigQuery API using Google App Script. The tables are relatively small for throuwing such error. Any help will be highly appreciated. It runs two queries back to back. Till a few weeks ago it ran perfectly fine.

Query  1. I am joining two tables. Both tables accumulate data everyday. One table (revRaw) is large, > 11000 rows. Other table, cmpnMeta is smaller. It's meta information for all campaigns whose performance info is captured in table 'revRaw' from our ad server. So the join would have performance and meta info for campaigns.

Query  2. In the join, depending on the value of a particular field and adType, I am updating the value of another field.

** Please note that the actual query brings in many more field than my code shows here. I edited out the ones that are irrelevant here.

Error throws up at Line 48:

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
```

---

```
function saveQueryToTable() {
 // destination dataset and table id
  const datasetId = "destination_dataset_ID";
  const tableId = "destination_table_ID";


  const query = "SELECT revRaw.date AS revRawdate, revRaw.adType AS adType, cmpnMeta.slaStartDate AS slaStartDate, cmpnMeta.slaEndDate AS slaEndDate, cmpnMeta.cmpnStartDate AS cmpnStartDate, cmpnMeta.slaRevenue AS slaRevenue, (cmpnMeta.slaRevenue / cmpnMeta.slaImpression) * revRaw.impressionDelivered AS directRevenue FROM [dataset1.revRaw] as revRaw LEFT JOIN [dataset1.cmpnMeta] AS cmpnMeta ON revRaw.campaignName = cmpnMeta.campaignName GROUP BY ...... : 


const updateQuery = "UPDATE `" + datasetId + "." + tableId +"` SET directRevenue = 0 WHERE adType = 'Direct' AND (slaRevenue <= 1 OR slaRevenue IS NULL)";


  resolveQuery(query, updateQuery, datasetId, tableId);
}

function resolveQuery(query, updateQuery, datasetId, tableId){
  const projectId = 'possible-stock-172109';

  var destinationTable = BigQuery.newTableReference();
  destinationTable.datasetId = datasetId;
  destinationTable.projectId = projectId;
  destinationTable.tableId = tableId;

  var myJobQueryConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
  myJobQueryConfig.allowLargeResults = true;
  myJobQueryConfig.query = query;
  myJobQueryConfig.writeDisposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE";
  myJobQueryConfig.destinationTable = destinationTable; 

  var myJobConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
  myJobConfig.query = myJobQueryConfig;

  var myJob = BigQuery.newJob();
  myJob.configuration = myJobConfig;

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(myJob, projectId);
  Logger.log(jobResult);

  var jobId = jobResult.jobReference.jobId;
  Logger.log(jobId);

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  var queryResults= "a";
    while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);



    //send notification/write to sheet or nothing
  }

  // Update impressionDelivered to 1 where adType = 'Direct' AND (slaRevenue <= 1 OR IS NULL)
  if(queryResults.jobComplete){
    var updateQueryConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
    updateQueryConfig.allowLargeResults = true;
    updateQueryConfig.useLegacySql = false;
    updateQueryConfig.query = updateQuery;

    var updateJobConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
    updateJobConfig.query = updateQueryConfig;

    var updateJob = BigQuery.newJob();
    updateJob.configuration = updateJobConfig;

    var updateResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(updateJob, projectId);

    var updateJobId = updateResult.jobReference.jobId;
    Logger.log(updateJobId);

    // Check on status of the Query Job.
    var sleepTimeMs = 500;
    var updateQueryResults= "a";
    while (!updateQueryResults.jobComplete) {
      Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
      sleepTimeMs *= 2;
      updateQueryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, updateJobId);
    }

    Logger.log(updateQueryResults);
    Logger.log("---------------------------------------");
  }

   Logger.log(queryResults);
}
```

Comment: How many rows come out of the join? Instead of guessing, it would be good to check.

Comment: hey Elliot, thanks a lot for noticing this and responding. It would be less than 12K rows. Do you want me to share the code provately with you? Give me your email ID please.

Comment: "It would be less than 12k rows". But how do you know for sure? I have the feeling that your left join is producing more rows than you assume that it is.

Comment: Oh I have to run the same query manually, I mean through web UI or otherwise, to get the results for next process. That's how I know it's less than 12K now. This query is a part of a long chain of operations written on app script.

Comment: So, since the nested queries inside the script are running just fine on web UI, is it a bug of bigquery API?

Comment: Faced a strange scenario. I deleted about 5000 rows from the left table and ran the script. This time no 413 error, but got a 'memory limit exceeded' feedback. Though the query record showed the query ran, the results were not copied to the destination table.